# Cassandra Input Step in Pentaho Spoon throws Read Negative Frame Size Error

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, pdi

I am using PDI 4.4.0. In the Cassandra input step, I am unable to read data from cassandra. Following is my stack trace.

```
rg.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2113929216)!
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:471)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:456)
at org.pentaho.cassandra.CassandraConnection.setKeyspace(CassandraConnection.java:154)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputDialog$10.widgetSelected(CassandraInputDialog.java:459)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputDialog.open(CassandraInputDialog.java:632)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:136)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:7835)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:2749)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1221)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7044)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8304)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:580)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

I am not able to read the data using show schema button too. For localhost Cassandra, I tried to change `thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 16. Intial value was 2. Is there any configuration to be made in PDI? Please help.

Comment: I have found a temporary fix. I created the table in Cassandra DB using the CLI client instead of CQL and tried to fetch the data from that table. It worked. While I am still unable to fetch the records from the table created using CQL.

Comment: if it' a thrift problem try creating the cql table with the additional [WITH COMPACT STORAGE;](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_v3f_vfk_xj__using-compact-storage) clause appended to the creation statement. This will make the cql table backwards compatible with thrift.